# how to show a spinner till the time data recieved from the server in angular2

Tags: angular

The project have a service.ts to make ajax call(http.post) and several components(abc.component.ts, bcd.component.ts etc) gets the data from the server through service.ts

I am using `<div class="spinner"></div>`  for the spinner view. But, need a better approach to show loader either gif etc.

I want to show a spinner till the time each component fetch data from the server. How to do that?

### service.ts

```
 getdata(){
      let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        let url = "http://883.82./Ser/soSe"; 
        return this.http.post(url, clientJson).map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
```

### abc.component.ts

```
let clientJson = {
        "aoId": "M_AO_918",
        "viewBys": ["usstate"],
        /* ... */
    };
  this.DataService.getdata(clientJson).subscribe(
        success => this.abcChart(success),
        error => this.errorMessage = error
    );
abcChart(jsonData) {
    /* ... */
}
```

### bcd-chart.component.ts

```
 initData() {
        let clientJson = {
            "aoId": "M_AO_918",
            "viewBys": ["brands"], 
            /* ... */ 
        };
        this.DataService.getdata(clientJson).subscribe(
            success => this.bcdChart(success),
            error => this.errorMessage = error
        );
    }
    bcdChart(jsonData) {
        /* ... */
    }
```

### styles.css

```
.spinner {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #333;

  margin: 100px auto;
  -webkit-animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-rotateplane {
  0% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) }
  50% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) }
  100% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg)  rotateX(180deg) }
}

@keyframes sk-rotateplane {
  0% { 
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) 
  } 50% { 
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg) 
  } 100% { 
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
  }
}
.loading{
  background-color: #d35400;
}
```

Comment: I am using <div class="spinner"></div> for the spinner view. But, need a better approach to show loader either gif etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main html file where you keep `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` you need to keep the html of spinner so you can show it in any component throughout your angular app :

You also need to import service in the `app.component.ts`:

app.component.ts:

```
constructor(
  public serviceName: ServiceName
  ...
)
```

app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div *ngIf="serviceName.showSpinner" class="spiner">
    <!-- svg or gif of spinner  -->
</div>
```

In your service.ts:

```
public showSpinner: boolean = false;

getdata() {
    // show spinner when we start making request

    this.showLoadingSpinner();
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let url = "http://883.82./Ser/soSe"; 
    return this.http.post(url, clientJson,clientJson1).map((res: Response) => {
      // response received so hide spinner now
      this.hideLoadingSpinner();
      return res.json();
    });
}

showLoadingSpinner() {
    this.showSpinner = true;
}

hideLoadingSpinner() {
    this.showSpinner = false;
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById` in Angular ? Should never use dom manipulation in Angular, atleast for these trivial things.

Comment: @Skeptor u r right. I had incorrectly assumed that `abc` and `bcd` might not have a common parent, but i forgot about the `<router-outlet>`, i have edited my answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: No matter what the case , You should never do direct dom manipulations in Angular :)

Comment: I am using vanilla JS on the client side. How do I show animation until data is received from the server in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Just have a boolean to track if the call is in progress or not

```
public inprogress = false;
```

set it to true before the http call and set it to false after the response is received

```
initData() {
    this.inprogress = true;
    this.DataService.getdata(clientJson).subscribe(
        success => this.bcdChart(success),
        error => this.errorMessage = error
    );
}
bcdChart(jsonData) {
    this.inprogress= false;
    /* ... */
}
```

If you like it keep it simple and handle in both error and success and not pollute `bcdChart` method you can do this way.

```
this.DataService.getdata(clientJson)
    .do(res => this.inprogress=false) 
    .subscribe(
        success => this.bcdChart(success),
        error => this.errorMessage = error
    );
```

Comment: Thanks @Skeptor, but also wants to show a spinner till the time data loads in background.

Comment: Can you explain 'data loads in the backgroind'

Comment: I mean till the time components fetch data for the view.

Comment: Subscribe gets called only after the data is fetched , right ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but want a better approach for spinner view as well.

Comment: In your HTML you use if else and either show the spinner or data . I dont understand why this is not a good approach. good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a function called show spinner

   get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable {
           this.showLoader();

   ```
       //return super.get ....
   ```

   }

2.after success hide loader

```
private showLoader(): void {

            this.loaderService.show();
}
 private hideLoader(): void {
            this.loaderService.hide();
}
```

3.Add Loader component

```
    import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
    import { LoaderService } from './loader.service';
    import { LoaderState } from './loader';
    @Component({
        selector: 'angular-loader',
        templateUrl: 'loader.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['loader.component.css']
    })
    export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit {
    show = false;
    private subscription: Subscription;
    constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) { }
    ngOnInit() { 

            this.subscription = this.loaderService.loaderState
                .subscribe((state: LoaderState) => {
                    this.show = state.show;
                });
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
         this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    }
```

4. Loader component view
5. Loader Service

   ```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
   import { LoaderState } from './loader';
   @Injectable()
   export class LoaderService {
   private loaderSubject = new Subject<LoaderState>();
   loaderState = this.loaderSubject.asObservable();
   constructor() { }
   show() {
           this.loaderSubject.next(<LoaderState>{show: true});
       }
   hide() {
           this.loaderSubject.next(<LoaderState>{show: false});
       }
   }
   ```